# Apache RewriteRule doesn't apply

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-shortener

I'm trying to create a **URL shortner** for my site, which any request to **`example.com/u/*`** should be rewritten to **`example.com/cpp-cgi-test.cgi?*` !**

Note that: the directory **`/u`** doesn't exist and I added it to URL only to prettify the short link!

**I'm on a cloud hosting provider environment with *Cpanel*; not a server!**

---

**Content of `.htaccess` under public_html:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/u/(.*)" "/cpp-cgi-test.cgi?$1" [NC]

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**Where only three first lines added by me!**

---

**Problem is:**

When I'm trying to access **`example.com/u/Abcde`** it ends up with a **`error 404`!**

Also, I tried the code below only in case of that the problem because of the fact **`/u`** directory doesn't exist; but with this code when I enter **`example.com/cpp-cgi-test.cgi`** still I'm not going to index.html:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/cpp-cgi-test.cgi" "https://example.com" [NC]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do let us know for URL `example.com/u/Abcde` in front end which EXACT url from backend you want to rewrite it? I suspect you want to add a query string to `cpp-cgi-test.cgi` also? Kindly confirm it once, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for such a generous welcome! yep, as you can see in `RewriteRule "^/u/(.*)" "/cpp-cgi-test.cgi?$1" [NC]` it's exactly what you said! **I'm trying to add anything after `/u/` to the `cpp-cgi-test.cgi` as query string! and the `*` meant to be wildcard.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following Rules in your .htaccess file, considering that any URI which starts from `u|U` should be re-written to `cpp-cgi-test.cgi` file in backend with a query string passed to it. Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)/?$ cpp-cgi-test.cgi?$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Tnx for fastest possible answering ever! I deleted `Options +FollowSymLinks` from first line and replaced two lines you gave! but would you please let me know what the problem was? bcs in the **[Apache website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html)** it used **`/`** before **`u`**!

Comment: @Shahaboddin, when you use `RewriteRule` then we need NOT to match `/` in starts it should be only matched in `REQUEST_URI` variable, hence the problem. This `^/cpp-cgi-test.cgi`(from your attempt) will never match, sicne it never starts from`/` in RewriteRule section.